# WooCommerce emails not being triggered by this code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created these email templates with WooCommerce booster:

[image]

and am trying to manually send them off using this code. Everything works except the Custom_6 and Custom_7 emails.

```
<?php
    add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status', 10, 1 );
    
    function woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status( $order_id ){
        
        if( ! $order_id ) return;

        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        $payment_gateway = $order->get_payment_method();

        if ($payment_gateway == 'invoice') {
                
            $order->update_status('wc-pending-inv', 'order_note'); 

            //sending emails
            //customer
            WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_WCJ_Custom_6']->trigger( $order_id );
            //admin
            WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_WCJ_Custom_7']->trigger( $order_id );
            WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->trigger( $order_id );

        }
    }

?>
```

Unfortunately, the **WC_Email_WJC_Custom_6** and 7 do not send emails, but the **WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order** does. Am I missing anything here? Perhaps the trigger shouldn't be order id?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If mail not working you should follow a few steps:

1. Before check WordPress mail you should Check mail working on your server or not? because if your server does not respond you can't send mail any how. So your test the server first like this(very simple way):

   a) Create a new page on your root folder(WordPress folder) like **test.php**

   b) Open link https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp and copy mail code and past on test.php and change mail and run, If you got mail means there is no any server issue.

   c) If you did not get mail, means it's your server issue. so you should be fixed first or you can send mail to your server support regarding this "Mail not working on my server"

But ff you got a mail from test.php means server is working then you can move on your woocommerce thankyou page mail:

**Case 1:** download any SMPT plugin like this https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/ and set up then again place the order and check the mail.

**Case 2:** If you not getting mail then update thankyou page functionality by using function.php:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status', 10, 1 );
 function woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $wc_emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();
    if( empty( $wc_emails ) ) return;

    if ($order->has_status( 'on-hold' ))
        $email_id = 'customer_on_hold_order';
    elseif ($order->has_status( 'processing' ))
        $email_id = 'customer_processing_order';
    elseif ($order->has_status( 'completed' ))
        $email_id = 'customer_completed_order';
    else
        $email_id = "pending";

    foreach ( $wc_emails as $wc_mail )
        if ( $wc_mail->id == $email_id )
            $wc_mail->trigger( $order->get_id() );
}
```

Comment: Hey mate, Mail is working. Normal orders get sent emails and everything is okay. I'm just trying to manually send an additional custom email (as seen in the code above).

This line works:
        WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->trigger( $order_id );


But these two don't
//customer
        WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_WCJ_Custom_6']->trigger( $order_id );
        //admin
        WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_WCJ_Custom_7']->trigger( $order_id );